# javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed; How to solve that issue?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

This is my code.
...

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "false");
properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.required", "true");
Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

//create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server

try {
    store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    store.connect(host, username, password);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

...

This is working in my local machine. when i deploying to the server this shows me an error.

'''

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:218)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at com.objectone.aws_demo.config.EmailConfiguration.config(EmailConfiguration.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Constructor
```

...

How to solve that issue? I have telnet to the telnet pop.gmail.com 995.
telnet also working.

Comment: Looks like a networking issue rather than a Java issue. You should check, from your server, if it has access to the host you specified at port 995. If not, you should check why: is it a DNS issue? Firewall issue? If the program works, then the problem is not in the program.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).  There's probably an anti-virus or firewall preventing you from connecting.